# Can someone explain why the row is not wrapping the text in this TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am having trouble with this for some reason... The column with the "name" shouldn't take up as much space as it does. The column does not wrap the text. The setup below is what I've been using and it has worked previously. What am I missing? Could there be something up with Eclipse?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#333333"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow android:layout_margin="1dp" android:background="#333333" android:gravity="center">
<TextView
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="Friends"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="22dp" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:layout_margin="1dp" android:background="#000000">
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="Name"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="15dp" />
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="Address"
android:textColor="#66cccc"
android:textSize="15dp" />
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="Interests"
android:textColor="#006666"
android:textSize="15dp" />
</TableRow> 
<TableRow android:layout_margin="1dp" android:background="#000000">
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="This is short"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="13dp"
android:width="0dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="This is some text that might be too long and might need to wrap to the next line."
android:textColor="#cc0033"
android:textSize="13dp"
android:width="0dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#222222" />
<TextView
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="3dip"
android:text="This is some text that will be long so it needs to wrap and go to the next line blah blah blah."
android:textColor="#99cc00"
android:textSize="13dp"
android:width="0dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried making the text smaller in your textviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html):

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

That might be causing some problems although the wording of that suggests to me that it should ignore your settings anyway and just overwrite them. Still, it might be worth getting rid of your `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes in those `TextViews` in your `TableRows` and seeing if it helps.

**Update:**

Just noticed you have `stretchColumns` set to `*`. Change it to `1,2`.

Comment: I removed all of the layout_height and layout_width attributes and it's still happening

Comment: Just added a suggestion for `stretchColumns`.

Comment: Thanks! That got the two last columns working right but STILL the problem remains with the first column (name) not being wrapped. It takes up nearly 1/3 of the screen when it should only be as long as the name entered.

Comment: I took your layout, put it in a new project, removed the unnecessary `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes and changed `stretchColumns` from `*` to `1,2` and it looked fine to me. The first column width was just enough to fit the name.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the code, deleted the xml, recreated it, and pasted the code again and it works... Can't explain that...

Comment: Sometimes resources get in a weird state in Android. A Project -> Clean probably would've worked too.

Comment: This is probably good for another question but have you ever had trouble getting the Graphical Layout for xml to look right? When I put a \n in my strings for the new line character it doesn't change it to the new line in the Graphical Layout.

Comment: Graphical Layout Editor is not very reliable in general. You can use it for a quick look, but never really trust it.